# How should I use C++ constructor exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I've never tried using C++ exceptions until a few days ago, and I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. I'm trying to throw an exception on a constructor that fails, like

```
X::X() {
    /*...*/
    if(error)
        throw;
    /*...*/
}
```

And using it like:

```
try {
    X a;
    X b;
    X c;
}
catch (...) {
    // error handling
}
```

The debugger (VS) says there's an unhanded exception on the throw. Code after throw gets executed (I though throw worked like return), and the catch block isn't executed. What am I missing here?
I may have oversimplified this post a little bit, but the original code is a bit complex to post here.

Comment: Could you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you do not throw an exception object. You should use throw like this:

```
throw std::runtime_error("Error message");
```

then you'll be able to catch it via

```
try {
    ...
} catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
    /* Handling */
}
```

Have a look at the [`stdexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept) header.

Comment: This would be clearer if instead of talking about an "exception type" it referred to an "exception object" or just "something". The  current working suggests that you need to throw something of a special type, but you can throw pretty much anything (as long as it is *something*).

Comment: I changed it, should watch my language more, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should [`throw` some exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) (generally an instance of some subclass of [std::exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception)), e.g.

```
X::X() {
   /*...*/
   if(error)
       throw std::runtime_error("my bad");
   /*...*/
}
```

See [std::runtime_error](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/runtime_error/) for more.

[`throw;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch) without any exception makes only sense inside a [catch block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw).

I agree with [Danvil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20827768/841108): throwing an exception inside a constructor is poor taste.